# Which PayPal method can used to Make background payment process to transfer money to a PayPal email id in PHP

Tags: php, paypal, background-process

Which payment method of PayPal can be used to transfer money to a PayPal email id in background process in PHP Programming.??

Comment: sorry, no idea what you are asking

Comment: What do you mean by background process ? Could you care to elaborate ?

Comment: Transfer money to a PayPal email id without redirect to PayPal site.

Answer (score 0):

Paypal is payment Gateway so It provides lots of features for payment integration. About your concern which kind of business logic you are using is all upto you. But I can give some Examples.

1) For Those whose business is very small and don't want to dig his/her head in more complex SDK involvement. 
Use : [paypal Standard](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/web/)

2) For those whose want same feature as standard but not wanting to display parameter's and all the developer stuffs.
Use :[Paypal Express](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReference/)

3) For those whose wants to merchant functionality with advanced features such like credit/dabit, bank transfer and all stuff
Use : [Paypal PRO](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/paypal-payments-pro)

4) For paypal email transfer 
Use: [paypal Payout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payouts/)